# How to detect computer/laptop's screen in an image?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation, edge-detection

I am trying to detect the screen of the monitor either computer or laptop.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj99H.jpg)

[Points of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wUjp.jpg)

First picture is the original image, second image marked with points of the rectangular area I want to detect in an image.
I have tried to get the screen by using `cv2.findContours` with opencv by this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/04/21/building-pokedex-python-finding-game-boy-screen-step-4-6/) but it didn't help. In [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/04/21/building-pokedex-python-finding-game-boy-screen-step-4-6/) he had the frontal picture of the screen but I have angular images mostly(videos) so it crashes to grab good contours and define the screen.

Code I used to find the screen:

```
import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2

from PIL import Image 
args = {
   'query': '/Users/PC/Desktop/screendetect/mm.jpeg'
}
class dotdict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]

args = dotdict(args)
# load the query image, compute the ratio of the old height
# to the new height, clone it, and resize it
image = cv2.imread(args["query"])
ratio = image.shape[0] / 300.0
orig = image.copy()
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 300)

# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and find edges
# in the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, 11, 17, 17)
edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 30, 200)

# find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[:100]
screenCnt = None

# loop over our contours
for c in cnts:
# approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.03 * peri, True)

    # if our approximated contour has four points, then
    # we can assume that we have found our screen
    if len(approx):
        screenCnt = approx
        break

# draw a rectangle around the screen
orig = image.copy()
d = cv2.drawContours(image, [screenCnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
cv2.imwrite("/Users/PC/Desktop/screendetect/test_good.jpg", d)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
```

In other test images there will be only one monitor so I need to find only one screen. What is the best approach to tackle this kind of problem?

Comment: If you are okay with using markers, maybe consider using Aruco markers? In case of angular images, you might also need to play with homography first.